# Closure relative to addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm working with an old Introduction to Linear Algebra book by Gillet, and in the book he claims that a subset of a vector space is guaranteed to be a subspace if it satisfies closure relative to addition and scalar multiplication. I've also heard my teacher mention something similar to this effect when we were working one-on-one. I'm not entirely following how all of the other vector space axioms (additive identity, scalar multiplicative identity, etc.) arise from just closure. Could someone please elaborate on this for me? I've seen related questions, but all of them seem to be about proving a subset is a subspace for a specific problem, rather than the general logic involved.

Comment: as it's a subset of a vector space it inherits the axioms, so you just need to show it is closed.

Comment: Not all subsets inherit all of the axioms. For example, consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. The subset of vectors $ \{ x:  2 < |x| < 4 \}$ doesn't have an additive identity. Examples like these are why I'm unclear what exactly is being inherited, what the vector space automatically gives to any subset.

Comment: but it's not closed either because (3,0)+(3,0)=(6,0)

Comment: _Most_ of the axioms are automatically inherited, once you have closure under the operations. For example it's clear that $x+y=y+x$ is inherited. Go through the axioms carefully, and you'll see every one of them is ok, _if_ you assume the subset is closed under the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $U \subset V$, where $V$ is a $K$-vector space, is closed under addition and scalar multiplication (here K is the underlying scalar field, which "usually" is $\mathbb{R}$).

Now, if $U$ is empty, there is nothing to prove. So let $x \in U$. We have that $-1 \in K$. Thus $(-1).x=-x \in U$, by multiplicative closure. Also, $x+(-x)=x-x=0 \in U$, by additive closure. Thus we have shown that additive identity is contained in $U$.

It is clear that distributivity of addition over scalar multiplication, associativity and commutativity, are induced by the same properties which hold in $V$ - they hold for all elements of $V$, thus for all elements of $U$.

Similarly, the multiplicative axioms follow immediately by the fact that they hold for all $v \in V$ and thus for all $u \in U$.